# emulating a controller with a raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am a pc mouse and keyboard gamer, mainly playing big fps titles on my laptop. and I was thinking to try to get controller aim assist on mouse and keyboard inputs, however there are many dongles that can do theses kinds of things, such as xim apex. however they are all very expensive and usually have to pay an additional fee to use their custom profiles. I was thinking that I had a few raspberry pi 4B sitting around from a previous project. and that I could repurpose them to turn my inputs to into controller inputs. however I cant find any code or ways to emulate a HID. or anyone that has done similar things, although I have a basic coding background I just don't know where to start.

I am expecting to connect my mouse and keyboard to my raspberry pi and then use my raspberry pi to convert my input to a gaming controller output